# Git 'Please tell me who you are' - VSCode - Unable to Start Dev Container

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a development environment using Docker due to compatibility issues I had locally. I'm using the Remote Development Microsoft extension within VSCode to do so by opening a folder of the local cloned repo which contains a Dockerfile. The aim is to open the folder in a container. I get an error of:
`An error occurred building the image`
Which results from the preceding error:

```
#6 859.0 *** Please tell me who you are.
#6 859.0
#6 859.0 Run
#6 859.0
#6 859.0   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
#6 859.0   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
#6 859.0
#6 859.0 to set your account's default identity.
#6 859.0 Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
#6 859.0
#6 859.0 fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@buildkitsandbox.(none)')
------
```

How can I resolve this error without editing the repository contents? Despite the error, when I use `git config --list` it shows my correct username and email.

Comment: Just because something is set in your home directory doesn't mean it's set in _your Docker container_'s home directory. If you want to plumb `~/.gitconfig` (or any other specific location) through, consider mounting it as a volume.

Comment: ...that said, "without editing the repository's contents" may not be possible, if you're defining "the repository's contents" to refer to the Docker image you're getting from a repository, and you're unwilling to build your own image that's derived therefrom (but with a Dockerfile patched to fix the bug). We could only investigate whether that _is in fact_ necessary if you pointed us to the specific image, of course; without that detail, the problem can't be reproduced, so proposed solutions can't be tested.